# Context Sensitive Grammar for the language $\{ a^{2n} b^{2n+1} c^{3n} d^{n+3} \mid n \ge 1\}$

Tags: context-sensitive

I have been trying to find a context sensitive grammar for the language $\{ a^{2n} b^{2n+1} c^{3n} d^{n+3} \mid n \ge 1\}$ for some time but I cannot get it done. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following grammar the first block of productions ensures that the right amount of $a,b,c$, and $d$ is generated, in some order. The terminal  $a$ is represented by the nonterminal $A$, $b$ by $B$, etc.
They also ensure that $X$, which represents a $a$, is at the end of the sentential form.

The next block ensures that $A,B,C,D$ can be reordered.

The last block ensures that terminals are generated from right to left in the correct order (first $d$, then $c$, then $b$, and finally $a$).

$$
\begin{align*}
S  &\to ABBCCCDS'X \\
S' &\to AABBCCCDS' \mid BDDD\\
\\
BA & \to AB \\
CA & \to AC \\
CB & \to BC \\
DA & \to AD \\
DB & \to BD \\
DC & \to CD \\
\\
DX &\to Xd \\
X &\to Y \\
CY &\to Yc \\
Y &\to W \\
BW &\to Wb \\
W &\to Z \\
AZ &\to Za \\
Z & \to a
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: my automata rejected this, does not seem to be correct because of order probably

EDIT: order is a b c d from left to right, but it seems to be getting correctly that part

Comment: Can you provide a sentence that is in the language but is not generated by the grammar, or a derivation of a sentence that is not in the language? Also there was a spurious  $S$ in right part the second production. I removed it.

Comment: Thanks, it works with that spurious S removed. Thank you some much for your time.