# Find CSG for $L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid 0 \leq i \leq j \leq k\}$

Tags: formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I am trying to find a context sensitive grammar for the type-1 language

$L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid 0 \leq i \leq j \leq k\}$

I can construct the first part with

\begin{align*}
S &\to aSbB \mid B \mid \epsilon\\
B &\to bB \mid \epsilon\\
\end{align*}

but how do I continue from there? I tried

\begin{align*}
S &\to aSbBcC \mid B \mid \epsilon\\
B &\to bBcC \mid \epsilon\\
CB &\to BC \\
C &\to cC
\end{align*}
but this does not seem to work e.g. $S \to aSbBC \to aaSbBCbBC \to aabBCbBC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
S &\to XABS' \mid XBS' \mid XS' \mid XAB \mid XB \mid X \mid \epsilon \\
S' &\to ABCS' \mid BCS' \mid CS' \mid C \\ \\
BA & \to AB \\
CA & \to AC \\
CB & \to BC \\ \\
XA &\to aX \\
X &\to Y \\
YB &\to bY\\
Y &\to Z \\
ZC &\to cZ \\
Z &\to c
\end{align*}
$$

For the intuition behind this construction see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124149/context-sensitive-grammar-for-the-language-a2n-b2n1-c3n-dn3-m/124150).

Comment: Technically, that's not a CSG, right? The last rule could only appear in a non-restricted grammar.

Comment: Right, I edited my answer.  Also the productions of the form  $PQ \to \alpha \beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have length at least $1$ and can contain both terminals and non-terminals, are technically not CS. However, they can be simulated as $PQ \to RQ, \quad RQ \to RU, \quad RU \to \alpha U, \quad \alpha U \to \alpha\beta$, where $R$ and $U$ are newly added non-terminals.